# getFiles() in Google Sites only returns 250 files

Tags: google-apps-script

How do I get getFiles() to fetch ALL the files in the folder in Google Drive. right now it only fetches the top 250 files and stops.

`var files = DocsList.getFolder('Mendeley Desktop').getFiles();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DocsList.DEFAULT_RESULT_SIZE` is currently 250, so by default, you'll get a maximum of 250 results as a response from `getFiles()`.

If you need more results, you can use the other `getFiles()` method, [`getFiles(start, max)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_docslist#getFiles) to get up to `DocsList.MAX_RESULT_SIZE` (currently 500) results at once, and use it with an offset to get the next `DocsList.MAX_RESULT_SIZE` files.

Comment: So I have to iterate 8 times with 500 items at a time untill it fetches all 4000 items.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it works... to get the remaining items you should use method `getFiles(start, max)` as explained [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_docslist#getFiles)